# How to make some fields hidden depending on value of other field AngularJS, Razor, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, angularjs, razor

I'm new in angularjs and razor. so please help me. I have such code

```
<div ng-app="">

    <p>Input page number to filter: <input type="text" ng-model="pageNumber"></p>

    <div class="table-bordered">
        @{
            string pageNo = "0";
        }
        @foreach (var item in Model.sol)
        {
            if (pageNo != item.TaskPageNo.ToString())
            {
                pageNo = item.TaskPageNo.ToString();

                <div id="PAGENUMBER" class="text-success" ng-show="**CONDITION**"><abbr title="select something">Page - @pageNo</abbr></div>
            }
            var pt = pat + item.Task_ID;
            <a href="@pt" class="btn btn-info btn-sm">@item.TaskNo</a>
        }
    </div>

</div>
```

I don't know how to set the CONDITION value using AngularJS...

I want to type into 'PageNumber' input box some value and filter pages, so the condition must be something like this

> if (PAGENUMBER.value.indexOf(pageNumber.value)>-1) { show this page
>   number } else { hide it }

The ID PAGENUMBER is only used here in question not in real code

How can I do this ? pleease help :)

Comment: how you use `id="PAGENUMBER"`? is this set dynamically? can you provide how it set?

Comment: No, I used PAGENUMBER here only to refer to the div, I don't have such ID in real code )

Comment: try see my answer, you can use idea from it

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your data using angular and then use ng-repeat over that data.  Then you can add a filter on the ng-repeat based of your input ng-repeat="item in items | filter: {pageNumber: pageNumber}":

Comment: thank you for reply, but I don't want to change the code, just want to add filtering

Answer (score 0):

if you set `PAGENUMBER` like `@pageNo`

for your checking you can use simple condition like

```
<div id="@pageNo" class="text-success" ng-show="'@pageNo'.indexOf(pageNumber) > -1"><abbr title="select something">Page - @pageNo</abbr></div>
```